# more than one binding for one attribute in like sql conditions, trying to DRY it up

Tags: sql, binding, find, conditional-statements, sql-like

## Not This:

```
"height like '%1%' or height like '%2%' or height like '%5%'"
```

Say there are a lot of bindings for just this one attribute.

They are not in order, they are random.

How can this sql be simplified?

## Something like this:

```
"height like ('%2%' or '%1%' or '%5%')
```

Code is just an example.

I'm not looking for injection suggestions.

Comment: Edited your code, first SQL statement didn't make sense. (Fix it if I'm wrong.)

Comment: Yup, I thought I missed something thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to IN for LIKE. Your first method is the correct approach.

```
WHERE (height LIKE '%foo%' OR height LIKE '%bar%' OR height LIKE '%baz%')
```

Note that this will be slow. You may want to look at a full text search instead.

Comment: right, solr is on heroku and there is also sphinx but solr looks like what heroku wants people to use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would think the SQL in option would solve your problem.

height in ('%2%','%1%','%5%')

This assumes your variables will always have values, so make sure your defaults are valid values in the DB!

Comment: [height like '%2%'] is not equivalent to [height = '%2']

Comment: Your right, for a moment there i had thoughts of PHP and that the percents were part of the Server side language. would work without them though

Comment: @Sam: `height like '%2%'` returns all rows where the character `2` appears somewhere in the column *height*. `height = '%2'` returns all rows where the column *height* contains exactly two characters: the character `%` followed by the character `2`

Comment: Also you can't use the % in an In statement, that was my problem.